# Extracting element from a list in Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

I want to extract the element '42' using only 'car' and 'cdr' in Scheme

```
(car (car ((0) (42 #t) (bar))))
```

However, I get an error message:

```
application: not a procedure; 
expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments 
given: 0 
arguments.....: [none]"
```

Comment: And the error message is ...?

Comment: "application: not a procedure; expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments given: 0 arguments.....: [none] "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, that's not a *list*. You're missing a quote... and hence Scheme is interpreting the expression as a procedure call (that's what the error is stating). This should fix it:

```
'((0) (42 #t) (bar))
```

Now, regarding your question - this is how to extract the number `42`:

```
(car (car (cdr '((0) (42 #t) (bar)))))
```

From right-to-left, the `cdr` skips the first element in the list, the first `car` extracts the `(42 #t)` sublist and finally the last `car` extracts the number. BTW, you can write all of the above in a shorter way, like this:

```
(caadr '((0) (42 #t) (bar)))
```